# Self-documenting java configuration framework

Tags: java, configuration, documentation-generation

I am looking for a configuration framework for java that can also be used to document the expected properties.  So, basically, when I request a property foo, I also want to be able to put in some documentation about what foo does, its default values, etc., and to have some way to get from the configuration framework a list of all requested properties, and their documentation.

I don't particularly care about the source format, but I do need hierarchical configurations.

I've looked at commons-configuration, typesafe config, owner, and a couple others, and I can't find anything that does this.

Is there a configuration framework that does this? Do any of the above do this, and I missed it?

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem right now. What did you choose to go with?

Comment: We haven't yet found anything, unfortunately.  We have the beginnings of such a system internally (https://github.com/unchartedsoftware/aperture-tiles/tree/develop/factory-utilities), which stores the information we need, but we haven't written the part that process that information into docs yet - we're still hoping to find something external with which to replace that module.  But so far, no luck :-(